# Which service (ubuntu 13.10) is putting my laptop to sleep when I close the lid?

Tags: 13.10, power-management, suspend, acpi

I run a netinstall of ubuntu 13.10. When I was on 12.10 I had a a sleep.sh script in /etc/acpid that would be invoked by the closelid event in /etc/acpid/events and then basically run pm-suspend.

I recently reinstalled the laptop and closing the lid put it to sleep even though I haven't yet installed my custom script.

What is causing the laptop to go to sleep then ?

Comment: That list is useless so I removed it.

Comment: Thanks, I should have pruned it of non-essentials items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is said to be a bug or weird feature in 13.10. To disable going into the sleep mode edit the /etc/systemd/logind.conf file and uncomment/modify/add the line:

HandleLidSwitch=ignore

Then execute sudo restart systemd-logind or simply reboot.

Also you might wanna check System Settings/Power and check the action not to suspend when lid is closed.

Comment: Note you can use `sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf` to edit the file, you can get a manual with `man logind.conf`, and I may have accidentally posted [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/U6xGB.png) image, which you can embed by adding `![image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/U6xGB.png)`. Great Answer :D

Comment: Editing /etc/systemd/logind.conf and replacing #HandleLidSwitch=suspend with HandleLidSwitch=ignore did it. Thank you.